# File Serving in JBoss 4.2.3?

Tags: apache, tomcat, jboss, alias

Right now I am using Apache to do some very simple file serving.  We also have a JBoss 4.2.3 instance that does all our application serving.  I'd like to just use JBoss for everything.  In Apache, I am doing the following in the httpd.conf file to perform the file serving:

```
Alias /reports "C:/driveReports/"
<Directory "C:/driveReports/*">
   AllowOverride All
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Is there something equivalent I can do in JBoss to accomplish the same thing?  It seems easy enough, but I haven't been able to find anything that leads me to believe there is a solution that doesn't involve Apache being linked to JBoss's Tomcat.

I know I could easily enough just move the files from their "C:/driveReports" location in to the JBoss web deployer location, but I'd rather not have to do that.  Thanks.

Comment: Putting Apache or some other proxy is a common practice. Apache is more efficient on serving static content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to take help from this wiki page about [static file serving](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/externaldirectories).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if JBoss AS has some such feature out of the box. It's an application server, after all.

You may use a servlet for such purpose, similar to Jetty's default servlet, with a code such like this:

```
private void dispatchFileForDownload( File file, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // Check the file existence.
    if( !file.exists() )
        throw new IllegalStateException("File "+file.getPath()+" does not exist.");
    if( !file.isFile() )
        throw new IllegalStateException("File "+file.getPath()+" is not a regular file.");

    // HTTP stuff.
    resp.setContentLength( (int)file.length() );
    if( artifactInfo.getFileName().endsWith(".jar") )
        resp.setContentType("application/java-archive");
    else if( artifactInfo.getFileName().endsWith(".xml") )
        resp.setContentType("text/xml");
    else
        resp.setContentType("application/octet-stream");

    resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+file.getName());


    ServletOutputStream os = resp.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(in, os);
    in.close();
    os.close();
}
```